# Create an array in python from two different arrays with all possible combinations with having fixed selection from each array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, combinations

I am trying to get the combinations of the two arrays with a fixed selection from each array.

Arrays:

```
X = ['A','B','C','D','E']
Y = ['1','2','3','4']
```

My condition for selection will be Sx = 3 and Sy = 2 (the output should have 3 elements from X and 2 elements from Y which are fixed)

The output should be similar to this with all possible combinations

```
XY = [('A','B','C','1','2'),('B','C','D','2','3'),....)]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use itertools

```
combos1 = itertools.combinations(X,r=Sx)
combos2 = itertools.combinations(Y,r=Sy)
prod1 = [a+b for a,b in itertools.product(combos1,combos2)]
```

this is computationally expensive ... it may take a while for big alphabets

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am able to get the result for the smaller array, as you mentioned it takes ages when the array size is in triple digits. Is there any alternative solution available for larger arrays?